# Linked In Marketing Developer Platform access request rejected, Is there is any other way to get linked-in connections list?

Tags: api, connection, linkedin-api

I am trying to access connection list of linked in.  I have tried to use GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/connections?q=viewer&start=0&count=50 connection API but getting access denied error. I also have applied for linked in market developer platform access for accessing connection api and filled all required information but it get rejected from linked In. Is there is any other way to get linked in connection list?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask specific questions Sachin. What are you trying to achieve, what data do you need? what is the API name you are trying to access etc. Generic questions are not helpful. Edit and update your question which shows the efforts that you have put in so far.